# Spring - @Value returns null

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a properties file under */src/main/resources/* and I want to load data from it using Spring.

In my Spring-context.xml I have this :

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:UserUtil.properties" />
```

and also have `<context:component-scan base-package="com.myApp" />`

and in my class I load it like :

```
@Value("${injectMeThis}")
private String injectMeThis;
```

but the value is always null

**EDIT:**

to check if the value, I use this :

```
System.out.println(new myClass().getInjectMeThis());
```

Comment: In UserUtil.properties do you have `injectMeThis=someValue`?

Comment: yes I checked, the value is there

Comment: It cannot be `null` if you did it correctly. Are you using the spring managed instance and not creating instances yourself with `new YourClass()`?

Comment: where is your `spring-context.xml`

Comment: this should work, you need to post more details to understand why it doesnt

Comment: My `spring-context.xml` is under WEB-INF, @M. Deinum I didn't get what you mean

Comment: If you are creating instances of the class yourself (the class containing the `@Value` annotation) nothing will be replaced.

Comment: and How will I use spring managed instance

Comment: Maybe gibe this a try `<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/UserUtil.properties" />`

Comment: You are creating a new instance yourself, how should Spring replace values in that. You should create an instance of the application context and retrieve the bean from there.

Comment: Your code should work. Make sure `UserUtil.properties` is in your classpath. And having `injectMeThis` property having some value.

Comment: @M.Deinum so I need to annotate my class with `@Component` and then autowire it so I can use it ?

Comment: Or create an instance in your xml file (you don't necessarily have to have `@Component`).

Comment: @M.Deinum put your solution as a response and I will accept it, it worked, thank you all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
System.out.println(new myClass().getInjectMeThis());
```

Spring will only parse `@Value` annotations on beans it knows. The code you use creates an instance of the class outside the scope of Spring and as such Spring will do nothing with it.

Assuming you have setup your application context correctly a `@Value` cannot be `null` as that will stop the correct startup of your application.

Your XML file contains a `<context:component-scan />` assuming `myClass` is part of that package the easiest solution is to add `@Component` to `myClass` and then retrieve the instance from the context instead of creating a new instance.

Answer (score -1):

In your class, add class level annotation `@PropertySource("UserUtil.properties")`. This should solve the problem.

Comment: That annotation will only be usable on `@Configuration` classes not other classes. Also that annotation without a `PropertySourcesPlaceHolderConfigurer` or `<context:property-placeholder />` doesn't do anything.

Comment: This will work for any components.Not just @Configuration class.

Comment: Then how come it is working for a class with @Component annotation?

Comment: It will work for `@Configuration` classes and lite configuration classes (basically it (kind of) works due to the conditions in the [`ConfigurationClassUtils`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/annotation/ConfigurationClassUtils.java#L80). So it depends on what your class is but it doesn't work for regular classes. (Next to that it also is a bit strange to have it not on a `@Configuration` class). But here it won't make a difference as that does (partially) the same as `<context:property-placeholder />`.

Comment: It do for a @Component class too. May be it is strange for a component to have it but just want to know why it shouldn't work for a component.

Comment: M.Deinum, can you please clarify on why @Component class should not use @PropertySource? and why it will not work if used together?