# Retrive value from yaml file to field in external library

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application
I have a external library (written by me, also using Spring parent) as dependency

In `application.yml` (in application, not in library) I have property `example`

In library, I have a class with code like this:

```
@Value("${example}")
private String example;
```

The value for this field is `null`, but when I'm calling for `Environmet` this value is accessible.
Any hint what should I do to get value by using `@Value`?

Comment: May be you forget add @Component annotation your class. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44542471/spring-value-returns-null

Comment: Yeah that was the case, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you forget add @Component annotation your class